# How to stop duplicates results when using group_concat mysql query

Tags: mysql, duplicates

following commands get all the foreign key query in given database schema, but it also response some duplicates foreign key's, so please tell me, someone, how to overcome this issue, and please give some example of a distinct option.

```
    SELECT SchemaName, GROUP_CONCAT(DropQuery SEPARATOR ';\n') as DropQuery
  FROM
  (SELECT 
  KCU.REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA as SchemaName,    
KCU.TABLE_NAME,
KCU.COLUMN_NAME,
CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', KCU.TABLE_NAME, ' DROP FOREIGN KEY ', KCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME) AS DropQuery 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KCU, information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS RC
WHERE
KCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME = RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
AND KCU.REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA = RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
AND KCU.REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA = 'jtrac') Queries
GROUP BY SchemaName;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your data, this answer is somewhat speculative.  If the problem be that a given schema name can have the same `DropQuery` value appearing more than once as CSV output, then we can try using `GROUP_CONCAT` with `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT
    SchemaName,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT DropQuery SEPARATOR ';\n') AS DropQuery
FROM
(
    -- your subquery
) Queries
GROUP BY SchemaName;
```